# Modifying free variable inside a closure in Scala

Tags: scala, closures

I wonder whether it makes sense to modify a free variable inside a closure. I can't find anywhere information whether it can be treated as a bad or good practice.

Simple example:

```
var a = 2;
val f = (x: Int) => {a = x + 2;}
f(2)
```

Is f a proper, state-of-the-art closure (is it at all a closure)?

Answer (score 2):

The main purpose of closures is to close over some state and be able to update it. Now you can pass function `f` somewhere and when you call it, `a` will be updated. So `f` is a proper closure. Is it a state-of-the-art? It depends on context and the role of this closure. In your case you can change `a` value either via `f` or directly reassigning `a`. So it isn't clear how do you want to update `a` and which way is preferable.

There are several ways to work with closures. You can use them to keep some state inside closure (see Lisp *cons* or *list* implementation). This way state is declared inside function and nothing can change it from outside. You just return another function - closure which is the only who has access to inner state.

Another example is *callbacks*. Actually your `f` looks more like [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming))  since it doesn't keep any state inside it but has a reference to `a`. So even if a is private you can pass `f` somewhere to be able to update `a`.